# Accessing a FormControl value that is in a nested FormArray

Tags: angular, formarray

Here is what I have (ignore unclosed divs, this is just for reference of the names):

```
<div *ngFor="let contact of VendorContactFormData.controls; let contactIndex = index; ">
  <div [formGroupName]="contactIndex">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <label for="phone">Phone</label>
        <div formArrayName="phones">
          <div *ngFor="let phone of contact.get('phones').controls; let a = index;">
            <div [formGroupName]="a">
              <input placeholder="Contact Phone" class="form-control" formControlName="phone">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
       ...
```

The data is set up so there is an array of contacts. Each contact has an array of phones. I want to access the value of the first phone of the first contact. This is the closest I have gotten:

```
this.VendorContactFormData.at(0).get('phones').value[0]
```

This returns {"phone":"216-621-5161"}. I'm trying to just get the phone number though, not the whole array element. I already have a formControlName "phone" for each element in the 'phones' array, but I have trouble accessing it. I tried

```
this.VendorContactFormData.at(0).get('phones').value[0].controls('phone').value
```

but I'm getting this error: 
"TypeError: this.VendorContactFormData.at(...).get(...).value[0].controls is not a function"

Any ideas?

Comment: You should try `this.VendorContactFormData.at(0).get('phones').value[0].phone`

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked!